# Modular Tree Add-on for 2.93.1

Tags: node-editor, add-on, modular-tree-addon

I want to use the modular tree add-on from Github, but it's only for Blender 2.8

https://github.com/MaximeHerpin/modular_tree/tree/blender_28

I tried to install it, but it only gives me empty nodes. I assume the addon is not compatible.

Does someone know where to get the latest version?

Thank you[image: modular tree addon empty nodes]

Comment: That repo is 4 years old and if there are no more repos of them for 2.93 then you are probably forced to use blender 2.8 that is compatible or find different addon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fix - I just had the same problem after starting a tree. After saving and reopening the file, the add-on nodes went blank just like yours. In this [discussion](https://github.com/MaximeHerpin/modular_tree/issues/277) you can download a fix for it. I've installed it and so far the add-on appears to work just fine.

However, the add-on didn't work with the tree I was working on, so you might have to start from scratch if you had work in progress.